# Functions from Scipy, Blas, or Lapack that compute only upper triangular matrix

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, scipy, lapack, blas

My goal is to transform a matrix into **upper triangular** form in Python. I know the function `scipy.linalg.lu` will do LU decomposition and compute **both** upper and lower triangular ones. I need to repeat this procedure several times. If there are functions from `Scipy`, `blas`, or `lapack` that compute only upper triangular matrix, the performance of my algorithm will be improved significantly.

Could you please suggest such functions? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click "source" on the `scipy.linalg.lu_factor` page,  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu_factor.html, it brings you to https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/linalg/decomp_lu.py#L17

which shows that the LAPACK function you're after is `*getrf`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but `getrf` computes both `U` and `L`.

Comment: Ok, then the answer in there isn't and likely there's no point :-)

Comment: Btw I really appreciate your interest in my question ^_^